# Almost every square matrix satisfies Cayley-Hamilton Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

I was watching [Steve Brunton's lecture](https://youtu.be/PrfxmkBsYKE) and he pointed out that Cayley Hamilton theorem is **not** true for **every** single square matrix, but it's true for almost every of them:

> Someone pointed out to me that this might not actually be true for every single square matrix $A$. So, almost every matrix $A$ satisfies its own characteristic equation. I don't want to get into the edge cases where this is not true. You can look this up in a linear algebra book and find out if this is true everywhere, but basically this is true for most matrices, OK? I think it might actually be true for every matrix...

Could you clarify what is the matrix which does not satisfy the theorem?

Comment: Write out your question, links are discouraged

Comment: Sorry for that. I removed the link. However, those are his words so I thought it would be better to add the link as a proof

Comment: Are there any other assumptions he's using? Are the matrices over some strange space or do they have some other properties?

Comment: Not at all. Actually it's the weird part because the lecture was more like elementary level. He just said he wouldn't get into some edge cases which CH is not true.

Comment: [every square matrix over a commutative ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) satisfies its own characteristic equation.

Comment: Steve who${}{}$?

Comment: Ohh so as long as we don't define our matrix on a commutative ring, we can say that it doesn't have to satisfy CH?

Comment: Was it [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrfxmkBsYKE)?

Comment: Yes it is the video

Comment: My best guess would be that there  was a confusion with "the characteristic polynomial of A  is the minimal polynomial of A" which is true for almost all yet not for all.

Comment: @quid That's what my professor said so

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brunton's comment is strange, [even in context](https://youtu.be/PrfxmkBsYKE?t=157). He claims someone unspecified pointed out to him there may be exceptions, but settles for claiming "almost every" square matrix satisfies the theorem, as he didn't want to elaborate on edge cases. (This is unfortunate for anyone who hopes they can *apply* the theorem at some point.)

The comments have discussed the fact that matrices not on a commutative ring may be exceptions, but I don't think he had these in mind. If he did, his language should have been more careful, because "almost every" means the set of counterexamples should be of measure $0$.

I actually think it's more likely that he and an unnamed colleague are data scientists and not linear algebra experts, leading to sloppiness on their part. What is true is that:

- in a commutative ring, $n\times n$ diagonalizable matrices "satisfy the theorem" (which I'm using as an unfortunate shorthand for $p_A(A)=O_n$);
- these are dense in the full space of $n\times n$ matrices in the commutative ring;
- this implies the non-diagonalizable ones satisfy the theorem too (because the characteristic polynomial is of finite degree, in finitely many entries of the matrix whose characteristic polynomial is computed).